# how to make the postgre SQL backup password protected

Tags: postgresql, security, backup, password-protection

I am backing postgre SQL db using pgadmin.

However, while the db has a password the backup file has no protection. The backup file can be taken and restored to any blank database without any password !!

How do I make the backup secure / password protected? Thanks.

Comment: You could use any tool to encrypt these files. For example https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL and PgAdmin have no built-in facility for backup encryption and password protection.

There are numerous ways you can encrypt backups. You can use gnupg, but I suspect you will be happier using a zip utility that supports encryption. I recommend 7zip, which supports the zip64 format and zip file encryption.

Comment: Yes, but I guess this will put the backup on disk first and that would defeat the purpose of encryption. However, if it can run without putting the backup on disk first ... it will serve my purpose well. Thanks.

Comment: @anil You can pipeline `pg_dump` output to an encryption tool. This works on Windows too, though it's more annoying there. For example, you can run `pg_dump .... | gpg -e -r 0xmykeyid -o mydb.pgdump.gpg` to encrypt with gpg. Similar options exist for using OpenSSL for symmetric AES, or whatever encryption tool you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I am using windows and its annoying :-).

Comment: I tried this and ran into issues. This is the command i used pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name  | 7za a -si -tzip -pmypassword -mAES256 c:/backup/dbsecure.zip and I get a system error saying "No such interface supported"

Comment: Well, does it work if you pipe some other arbitrary text into 7zip?

Comment: it works using gpg2 (windows version). Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a tool which supports streaming encryption - and avoid writing your plain text backup to disk. Also don't use pgAdminIII, but use pg_dump instead, and pipe the backup output into your encryption program, and write the result to disk.